# how to integrate twitter in android app

Tags: android, twitter

am trying to develop an android application that loads tweets for a particular hash tag from twitter. I only want to display the tweets for the  user. I do not want users to login into there twitter accounts while using my application. How can i go about this.

Comment: In order to not getting -1, it's good idea to search the site before asking general question like yours. Anyway, please look at: https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidTwitter

Comment: thanks for the quick answer Hesam, I have gone through a number of sites, and I have downloaded twitter4j and integrated it in my app. But most sites I have been to. show how to login and logout. and its not what am looking for. Am after displaying tweets, and only allowing users to read no commenting

Comment: follow this tutorial http://tech-papers.org/integrate-twitter-with-android-application/

Answer (score 3):

You can implement this  by using Search api of twitter which does not require authorization, this are public searches and you can use it to mine tweets which are publicly available.

now, i would suggest following.

1. Either user `Twitter4J` lib, they have pretty solid implementation hence with almost no effort you can perform integration.

http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/

2. Consume Twitter public search API directly, in this case you will get some space to perform customisations from your end if required.

https://dev.twitter.com/

Comment: I have already integrated twitter4j in my application and i also have a listview in my view where i would like the tweets to appear, But i dnt really know the next step

Comment: What you have done till now with twitter4j, put some code so that i can look upon.

Comment: I haven't done anything apart from setting up the views and the java to handle the views, because this is my first time to integrate twitter in any of my apps

Comment: Alright, means apart they importing twitter4j lib you haven't done anything specific, perform the following  first register yourself as as developer with twitter you get two keys in return, now create a twitter object using Twitter class from lib, read documentation for more information, using keys you got above initialize your twitter object, now without performing any authorization you can use twitter search api, this will return you all the public available result with your search criteria .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Twitter Helpe](https://github.com/krazykira/Twitter-Helper)r for integrating twitter